# Covering number definition, general metric space question.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

While reading "On the mathematical foundations of learning" by F.Cucker and S.Smale I came across this definition:

Let $S$ be a metric space and $s>0$. We define the covering number $\mathcal{N}(S,s)$ to be the minimal $ l \in \mathbb{N}$ such that exist $l$ disks in $S$ with radius $s$ covering $S$.

My questions are kind of silly. The first one is: are those disks are to be understood as open balls?
Second one: I do not know how to interpret that those disks are "in $S$". They cannot be subsets of S, because if they were, the covering number would be infinite if S wasn't a disk (open ball?) itself.

Comment: You can cover a sphere with two open discs - try it!

Comment: Also the answer to the first question is yes.

Comment: @Mike Miller Oh, I think I got it. Disks that are "in" S, when they are close to the surface, they actually are no longer shaped like disks, but like intersection of S and the disk. Is that right?

Comment: @ltw: Right. Here when we say discs we mean the open balls of the metric space. In the sphere, open balls around some point will look like curved discs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be a metric space. When the authors are talking about 'open discs' in $X$, they mean sets of the form $B(x_0, r) = \{x \in X : d(x,x_0) < r\}$. In Euclidean space $\Bbb R^n$ these actually look like discs; in other spaces, they don't need to. (Consider, for instance, the [torus](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c6/Simple_Torus.svg/310px-Simple_Torus.svg.png) with the metric it inherits from $\Bbb R^3$; if you pick a ball around the point closest to us with radius just big enough to contain every point on the 'meridian circle' it belongs to, this neighborhood will look like $S^1 \times (-1,1)$, roughly.)

So we define $\mathcal N(X,r)$ to be the minimal number of balls of radius $r$ we need to cover our whole space. Equivalently, this is the minimal number of points we need to pick such that every other point of our space is within $r$ of one of them. On the unit circle with the metric it inherits from $\Bbb R^2$, if we set $r=1.5$, this is two; the top and bottom of the circle suffice for our two points, but because the diameter of the circle is $2$, picking one point does not suffice.

For what's called a [compact space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space), this $\mathcal N(X,r)$ is *always* finite, for any $r>0$. To be compact means that for any collection of open sets $\{U_\alpha\}$ such that $U_\alpha$ cover $X$ (i.e., every point is contained in some $U_\alpha$), there is a finite subcollection $U_1, \dots, U_n$ that also covers $X$. Some familiar examples of compact spaces are spheres $S^n$, the torus, boxes $[-1,1]^n$...

Why is $\mathcal N(X,r)$ automatically finite? Consider the collection $\{U_x\}$, where $U_x = B(x,r)$ - so we have one open set for every point. By the assumption that $X$ is compact, we can pick a finite subcollection of this that covers all of $X$. So we're done!